# Robotic Process Automation (RPA) Express execution error

Tags: automation, rpa, workfusion, rpa-express

I have installed RPA express and recorded a process, but when I tried playing the recording it was showing an execution error " Unable to connect with robot". How can I get it resolved?

Comment: Did error resolved?

Answer (score 3):

Check Bot Manager status. Probably, it's not started.

1. To start Bot manager, open RPA Express tray menu and click Start in the Bot Manager section.
2. If it does not help, choose All Components > Restart