# Workfusion: Unable to connect with robot

Tags: rpa, workfusion

I have installed community edition of [Workfusion](https://www.workfusion.com/). 
But I am not able to play any recording due to the following issue:

> Unable to connect with robot
>   com.workfusion.studio.rpa.recorder.player.driver.DriverInitializationException: Unable to connect with robot.
>
> ...
>   ...
>
> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session.
>
> Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure
>
> .......
>
> Driver info: driver.version: RpaUniversalDriver
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:744)
>
> .......
>
> Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>         at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)

Can you help me resolve this issue?

I have already tried the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415564/robotic-process-automation-rpa-express-execution-error). No luck though.

Answer (score 1):

Try to open the tray menu and restart the Bot Manager component

Also check that the port 15444 is open.

You can also check the troubleshooting tips here - https://kb.workfusion.com/display/RPAe/Troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

I also found one **alternate way** if this above answer does not work.

- **Stop 'Jenkins' Service** which is running in the background by stopping it from 'Component Services' option. *(Search it using the Windows button)*
- **Stop all 'Java' processes** and then install Workfusion RPA Express. Start this program as well, and then restart all your stopped Java processes